# How to add division sign / times sign / plus sign in xcode 7?

Tags: xcode7

I'm using xcode 7, and learning ios development from the Stanford open class.
The teacher is using the xcode6 to build a calculator, he can add the (+, -, x & division sign) in the button, but in xcode 7 i can't find these character from the Edit->Special Characters. But there have 4 characters in bold and black. I can't set the color to blue. Is this a change in xcode7? How can i add the +-x% in the same font and style as the number buttons?
Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open Edit -> Emoji & Symbols.

Can you see a symbol at the right-up corner?

**Click it, and it is going to be the traditional interface.**

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean where to get the ✖️➗➖➕×÷-+ symbols? It is now `Edit->Emoji & Symbols`, but you can type things like `plus` into the search box to find the symbols. Or you can copypaste them from the internet, e.g., here… =)

As for the colour, change the `UIButton`'s `titleColor` or `UILabel`'s `textColor`. You may have to use the × ÷ - + symbols instead of the big bold ones to get the colour to change. You can still change the font to make them big and bold, e.g., the same ones are below:

## × ÷ - +

Programmatically it would be something like:

```
button.setTitle("×", forState: .Normal)
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 28)
```

Or you can use the interface builder.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by @hphphp.

To add more ease to it, please follow the screenshots to select any kind of symbol into your **editor or storyboard**

You can even search for the icons.

[image: Steps to add Emojis]